# How to avoid a circular dependency but pass information from a parent project?

Tags: c#, struct, memory-management

**Context:** I am working within a large solution which contains multiple projects. The goal is to pass in a simple user input (two arrays of ints of length 3, and a boolean) which is retrieved in project A, to project B where it is used by some function. Project B is a View model. However, project A references project B (as in, names project B as a reference), so to avoid circular dependency I cannot reference A from B.

As will be obvious, very much a beginner, but this is in a professional environment so there is only so much I can 'remodel'. I am working in Visual Studio.

**Thoughts:** The solution I can think of is, in project B, to generate at compile time some memory of those ints and bool. Then at run time, this is populated in project A, and then this information is retrieved by project B later on.

At the moment what I have doesn't do this at all, but I will post what I currently have. In project B I have, in a suitable file:

```
namespace NameSpaceB
{
  public struct Inputs
  {
    public int[] array1;
    public int[] array2;
    public bool t;
  }
}
```

Now heading to project A, it would be something like:

```
using NameSpaceB;

/* what follows is some structure already present in the solution, not my work */
namespace NameSpaceA 
{
  ... 
  internal public class MyClass
  {
    public static void MyFunction()
    {
      ...
      int[] inputs1 = { 1, 2, 3 }; /* assume these are inputs from a View model during run time */
      int[] inputs2 = { 4, 5, 6 };
      bool T = true;

      /* here is where I'd like something along these lines */
      Inputs inputInfo;
      inputInfo = default;

      Array.Copy(inputs1, Inputs.array1, 3);
      Array.Copy(inputs2, Inputs.array2, 3);
      Inputs.t = T;
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Now ideally, I'd like to retrieve the contents `inputInfo` in project B once MyFunction() has executed. There will be default inputs in my View project (appearing the UI) so hopefully there is always something 'there' to find in my arrays.

I think the way to do this is in project B, allocate memory at compile time for that struct, such that it is accessible to both projects at run time. I've done some Googling but am struggling to see how best to do this, or even if my idea is a good one.

Comment: Put the shared things in C and reference C from both A and B?

Comment: Yes, that would have been my first suggestion.  That said, I feel like there's too much hypothetical here to make your question meaningfully answerable.  Post your actual code please, not some hand-wavy fictional code.  What you've posted looks like it has several problems with it.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Ah I thought of this actually, but then it felt a bit wasteful to create a 3rd project purely to host this tiny amount of data. Unless I've misunderstood you?

Comment: Also, intuitively I feel like this isn't a memory management problem.  It's more of a design problem.  Your use of the term "View Model" suggests that you already have some UI framework available that solves these problems for you, like WPF or Blazor.  Use the framework properly, and you won't have to worry about this anymore.

Comment: You can't allocate memory at compile time anyway, not in any way that makes reasonable sense in C#.

Comment: @RobertHarvey frustratingly I do not think I am allowed to copy & paste actual code for company reasons. Not ideal when it comes to getting help but I thought the above would distil the material to what I am asking? :/

Comment: The title makes this sound like an XY problem.  Asking how to allocate memory at compile time is a **secondary** problem related to a specific approach to a solution to the **actual** problem you have, which may be (albeit slightly unclear) that you have a circular dependency in the declaration of types shared by two projects.  The title should probably be changed to represent the actual problem.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Indeed the design is the underlying issue; I've been asked to add a small functionality, but from my perspective it looks like this would entail circular dependency, as I need inputs that are received in A to be passed B, but because A has B as a reference, I can't explicitly snap anything from A within B.

Comment: The way you're proposing passing inputs is likely to lead to much frustration down the road.  You don't fix bad design by adding more bad design.

Comment: @Wyck Ok I've changed the title, let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: The title is improved, but I'm still not 100% convinced that you actually have a circular dependency.  If the `Inputs` type is declared in project B that's fine -- project A can use objects of type `NameSpaceB.Inputs` just fine.    The code you wrote seems reasonable.   Do you get an error or something?  What's the *actual* problem here?  What do you mean by _"I can't explicitly snap anything from A within B"_?

Comment: First of all, if you need to retrieve data generated and strored in A... B must Depend on A; as B need to read from it.
You must define the strut in A, and publish an instance of it accesible to B. I didn't see any problem, no circular dependency as you didn't need A depend on B

Comment: Do you understand the difference between value types and reference types?  Arrays are reference types.  If I say `var a1 = new int [] {1, 2, 3};` and then `var a2 = a1;`, what happens is that an array is created, and a reference to that array is copied to both `a1` and `a2`.  The array is not copied.  A `struct` is a value type.  When you assign a struct, its members are copied.  If I say `var in1 = new Inputs();` and I initialize the members of `in1` and then say `var in2 = in1;`, then I get a new copy of  `Inputs`, but still only one copy of each of the arrays.  Is that not what you want?

Comment: And, like others have pointed out, the solution to a circular dependency is a third assembly which the other two both reference.  But, you don't show a circular dependency in your code, so it's hard for us to point out how to do this.  In addition, this code: `Inputs inputInfo;` is wrong.  In C#, you need to initialize variables with either existing values (including literals: like `var i =0;`), previously constructed instances or with newly constructed instances.  The code should be `Inputs inputInfo = new Inputs();`.  Since `Inputs` is a value type, this will initialize the member to default

Comment: @Wyck so perhaps I was unclear (if so apologies) the potential circular dependency exists because elsewhere in the code, the NameSpaceB is referred to in project A. Therefore, in the visual studio, project A has project B in its list of references. In other words, A requires B, but B is not aware of A. So the problem is then how one can get information from A to B. Initially it seems that doing so requires B referring to A, but that would be circular.

Comment: @luaaa Nope that's not circular.  You get a project A depending on a project B and able to exchange data all the time.  Go ahead and code it up and demonstrate an error message, if you like.  Some details are missing because your `MyFunction` doesn't accept any arguments and doesn't call out to any external APIs or anything.  You just have a comment saying _"assume these are inputs from a View model"_.  Perhaps the details of the assumption are what's giving you trouble?  Or is it the return of this function that is causing you a problem?

Comment: Ok, so the need for A depend ond B is in another piece of the code, then ... as everyother says, to avoid circular use an intermediate dataStorage C Project...
Or you need to be sure of race conditions, (i.e. B will be on and ready when A populates Inputs?)

Comment: @J.Salas It's also fine if `Inputs` is defined in B.  I don't see a compelling reason to create a third project C yet.

Comment: @Wyck correct, but B must be up and with an instance of Inputs() ready to accept data from A, when data is generated there (A)
(you got me editing to complete my last comment :P )

Comment: OK, so maybe what we need to see here is a rough sketch of what code is desired to be written in B.  _ideally, I'd like to retrieve the contents inputInfo in project B once MyFunction() has executed._  The question sketches out A's code, but leaves the usage of the data in B a mystery.  At the most basic level, an approach is to expose a function from B that A will call to pass it the data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this much more complicated than it need to be. If project A wants to give some data to a method in project B, it would simply call the method. If said method takes a parameter of some type, that type would need to be in declared in project B, or some other project referenced by both A and B.

I.e. your example would be something like

```
public static void MyMethodInProjectA(){
    Inputs parameter = GetInputsFromSomewhere();
    MyProjectBClass.MyMethod( parameter );
}
```

This example assumes static methods. If you want to call a instance method you would obviously need to have reference to said object.

There are cases where the data might be expensive to generate, so you want to create it only when needed. In that case you can use indirection, for example by using delegates:

```
public class MyProjectBClass{
    public Func<Inputs> InputSource {get;}
    public MyProjectBClass(Func<Inputs> inputSource) => InputSource  = inputSource;
    private void MyMethod()
    {
        Inputs i = InputSource();
        // use the inputs
    }
}
public class MyProjectAClass{
    MyProjectBClass bClass;
    public MyProjectAClass(){
        bClass =  new MyProjectBClass(GetInputsFromSomewhere);
    }
    private Inputs GetInputsFromSomewhere(){
        // Create a input object and return it.    
    } 
}
```

This way MyProjectBClass does not need to care what is generating the inputs, it just need to depend on a standard delegate type.

Another thing that is sometimes useful are interfaces or base classes. Project B can create a interface that is implemented in Project A. This allows classes in Project B to use objects of classes in Project A, but only the parts exposed in the interface.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a *lot* to learn I think! So one question, how can project B call a method in project A, without writing "using NameSpaceA" in my project B file? Basically, the set up is this: an application with two 'pages' (unsure what the correct term is; two separate xamls). Inputs are fed into one of them, which is controlled by A, the other has a 'play' button, controlled by B. The idea is for the inputs on page A to be accessible when 'play' is hit. So in an ideal world, I'd want B to be able to do NameSpaceA.GetInputs(), but that's not possible...

Comment: @luaa See the example using a delegate. When the class in Project A creates the object from the class in Project B, it can give it a delegate (i.e. a `Func<T>`) that the class in Project B can call when it needs something. That way class in project B does not need to depend on anything in Project A, only on the delegate type and its parameters.